# S3F3 framework with sso credentials

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, python-s3fs

I'm exploring the `S3FS` framework which I need for reading/writing from/to the S3 file system.
From what I can see in [docs](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=credentials#credentials), we can pass the AWS credentials explicitly, but I don't see any information about SSO credentials.

I also tested this snippet of code to see if credentials from my environment were passed, but I'm getting error:

```
>>> import s3fs
>>> fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=True)
>>> fs.ls('my-bucket')
```

Is it possible to use SSO credentials in conjunction with the `S3FS` framework?